# Ctrl + C in dd broke 2 usbs

Tags: linux, usb, dd

So I was using dd to write a Windows ISO to my USB stick, and when I switched to tty 2 and back the status seemed stuck. I quickly pressed ctrl + c to start over but now the usb stick doesn’t show up in lsblk or as a special device (/dev/sdx). This same issue has happened on a different device where I had to go and used ctrl + C (was on a school computer). The disk shows up in lshw somehow though.

I’m sorry if my text is difficult to understand, English is not my first language

Comment: What does `dmesg` show after plugging in the USB sticks? Are both of the problematic sticks the same type? It's unlikely that `dd` has damaged them...

Comment: Well, now when I replugged the most recently damaged the system found it, but the first one I damaged is not. But it is showning up in lshw and this command you told me to run shows it too. https://pastebin.com/LQvLsEkW Can you take a look? :))

Comment: Line 960 looks like a ~32 GB stick that works (`USB DISK 2.0`, `idVendor=26bd`, possibly [Integral](https://www.integralmemoryplc.com/), possibly clone), Line 1357 looks like an unbranded stick that doesn't work (`USB2DISK`, `idVendor=ffff`)... not much more I can do to help, sorry.